# the col argument does not work in the barplot function with many values

Tags: r

I am trying to draw a plot using the barplot function with R version 3.6.1 under
Windows 10 Pro.

I need the fill color to be red and the border to be black, but using the following code `barplot(epc$GAP~epc$time,col="red",border="black")`
does not work as I expect, the fill color black and the border is black too.

[image]

**The expected result:** the fill color should be red and the border color should be black.

Comment: The problem seems to be that your bars are very 'close' together. Thus the `width` of each bar is equivalent to `0`. The `border` is thus the entire bar. I suggest combining multiple periods in your dataset, to widen to bar, or use a different plot to better visualize this behaviour.

Comment: @joran You're right, my problem is because I have fewer pixels than I try to draw. thanks.

Comment: @Oliver you right too, i changed my code by plot(epct$Time,epc$GAP, type="l") and works wonderful. thank you.